# How can I test a redirect call using react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I've got a react page:

```
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

export const App: React.FC<{router: any}> = ({router}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-full">
    <div className="h-1/8 text-center border-brand-primary border-2">Nav bar with login goes here</div>
    <div className="h-1/8 text-center border-brand-primary border-2">Pathways overview data goes here</div>
    <div className="flex-auto">
      <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<PageNotFound />} />
    </div>
    <div className="mt-64">
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

I have the routes setup thus:

```js
const routes = [
        ...Routes,
        {
          path: "*",
          element: <Navigate to="/thing/123" replace />
        }
      ]
```

I'm trying to write a jest test to test the redirect. So far I've gotten this:

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { createMemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

...

test('root sends redirect', async () => {


        const router = createMemoryRouter(routes);
        render(<App router={router} />);

        await waitFor(() => {
          expect(router.state.location.pathname).toEqual('/thing/123');
        }, {timeout: 5000});

      });
```

The problem is, the redirect never seems to happen inside the test. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

I've found lots of examples around react-router v4 and v5 but **none of those seem to be working with v6**. Worth noting, the redirect does work in the wild, but I can't seem to replicate that functionality in a unit test.

Comment: I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9508)